# Solving and optimizing a vector equation for time

Tags: optimization, vectors, parametric

I have a parameterized function of 3-d vectors defined as:
$$
t(A\vec{u} - \vec{v}) = \vec{p}
$$
Where $t$ is time, $\vec{u}$ is a variable vector, $A$ is a scalar constant, and $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{p}$ are vector constants.

I need to get this equation in terms of $t$, but there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to do this since it would involve division of vectors.

Once in terms of $t$, I must then find the vector $\vec{u}$ that minimizes $t$. I figure this part should be easy, as I can just take the derivative of the $t$ function with respect to $\vec{u}$ and set it equal to zero. However I first need to find the $t$ function, as mentioned above.

Comment: Idea: perhaps you could break the vectors to their components? Then you would have three scalar equations.

Comment: @MattiP. Yes I had thought of that, but then I'd have 3 equations and 4 unknowns (as opposed to 1 and 2) and I figure it would cause problems when trying to optimize t.

Comment: You could also have a geometric interpretation. Surely, $A\vec{u}-\vec{v}$ and $\vec{p}$ have to be parallel, so
$$
(A\vec{u}-\vec{v}) \cdot \vec{p} = \pm 1
$$
This could also help with the equations ...